# Undefined method `json' for #<ActiveRecord:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I have a create_table migration that looks like this:

```html
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :state
      t.string :coin_sku
      t.monetize :amount, currency: { present: false }
      t.json :payment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I run my rails db:migrate, it returns me an error message saying:

```html
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `json' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition:0x007f819fbb81b8>
Did you mean?  JSON
```

Has anyone ever had this problem before? Many thanks!!

Comment: Does SQLite support JSON columns? This might be something you need to use `text` for on that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know if you want to do this in SQLite3, you need to setup [serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) in the model. However, on that page it mentions,

> Keep in mind that database adapters handle certain serialization tasks for you. For instance: json and jsonb types in PostgreSQL will be converted between JSON object/array syntax and Ruby Hash or Array objects transparently. There is no need to use serialize in this case.

So I'm wondering if you were meaning to be using Postgres which looks like it might have a [json method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/ColumnMethods.html).

Comment: Haha You're right! I usually start every project with --database=postgresql and must have forgotten this time.. Now just need to change back over.. Thanks!

Comment: @Alec If you almost always want that command line option running `rails new --help` down in the description mentions "You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.". Never done it, but seems like it'd help accidentally forgetting an option